# LegendEntries collection not visible from Locals pane

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When I examine a [Legend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.legend) object in the **Locals** pane, I don't see the [LegendEntries collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.legendentries).

[image: LegendEntries used in code, but not visible in Locals pane]

I learned about LegendEntries only from [Microsoft's online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.legendentries).

**Why isn't LegendEntries visible from the Locals pane?**

What other options do I have to explore the object model besides the **Locals pane**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Object Browser, you can see that `Legend.LegendEntries` is a method (a `Function` or `Sub`); the Locals pane only displays properties (`Property Get`).

[image: Object Browser with arrows pointing to the LegendEntries member icon and description]

It's also presented this way in the [documentation of the member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.legend.legendentries) (not the [docs on the collection itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.legendentries), but about the member needed to access the collection from `Legend`):

> **Legend.LegendEntries method (PowerPoint)**

It's not that obvious in VBA, because VBA doesn't require parentheses when calling a method without parameters. But if you were accessing the PowerPoint object model from a language which does require parentheses for such method calls, you'd see the distinction right away.

Aside from the [Microsoft documentation of the Office object models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/), the **Object Browser** (**View** -> **Object Browser**, or pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>) shows all the members of a given type, including the methods.

---

<sup>NB. By default the Object Browser doesn't show "hidden members", nor are they visible in completion list in the code editor window. In order to see such members, right-click anywhere in the Object Browser and choose the **Show hidden members** option. The hidden members will be displayed in a lighter gray, as in the above screenshot.</sup>

<sup>Note also that code which uses these hidden members will compile and run successfully, whether or not this option is selected.</sup>

Comment: Okay. That is new to me. Thanks. Wonder how many other such neat Subs/Functions are hidden away and how to find them of course.

Comment: @Charlie AFAICT the only way is to read the documentation, or the Object Browser on whatever type you're looking at.

Comment: Okay. Marked as answered. Thanks again.

Comment: @Charlie right-click anywhere in the object browser and select the "show hidden members" option; the dim-gray items will now also show up in IntelliSense.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Legend.LegendEntries isn't a hidden member; so while your comment is accurate and important, it's not quite relevant to the question. (That was the first thing I checked.)

Comment: Your object browser screenshots are showing hidden members but the post makes no mention of that option. I was addressing this comment thread ("how many other such neat subs/functions are hidden away and how to find them"), not your answer, which I upvoted.